# Generated Url.Action() url, a parameter not matching by action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this action method in my `HomeController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult Form([FromQuery]string first, string last)
{
    InputModel model = new InputModel();
    // ...
}
```

I generate this action url like this:

```
@{ 
    var formUrl = Url.Action("Form", "Home", new { first = Model.FirstNameParam, last = Model.LastNameParam });
}
```

`Model.FirstNameParam` is string "Hello" and `Model.LastNameParam` is string "Hi", And I can see them in the following expression when debugging:

```
Url.Action("Form", "Home", new { first = Model.FirstNameParam, last = Model.LastNameParam });
```

The generated Url is:

```
/Home/Form?first=Hello&last=Hi
```

But the action method only receives the first parameter "first" and "last" parameter is null.

I use this in jQuery load method.

I played a lot with `[FromQuery]` and other attributes also tried to apply this attributes to other parameters but I still get last = null.

How to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contrary to when I see in debug mode, the Url.Action 's url was written to the page as `/Home/Form?first=Hello&amp;last=hi` so using Html.Raw changed &amp to & and problem solved.

```
@{ 
     var formUrl = Html.Raw(Url.Action("Form", "Home", new { first = Model.FirstNameParam, last = Model.LastNameParam }));
 }
```